# what are some applications of group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, applications

what are some applications of group theory? Group theory seems to be rather abstract.

Comment: See for finite groups: [real world applications of finite group theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324253/are-there-real-world-applications-of-finite-group-theory?rq=1)

Comment: wikipedia-ing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory#Applications_of_group_theory

Comment: I'm told that mathematical physics is crucially tied up with Lie groups.

Comment: besides, **abstractness** is not a crippled stage :D

Comment: @amWhy: the OP doesn't mention *finite*

Comment: @janmarqz Plenty of examples can be found there. See also all the related posts in the right-most column (heading: **related**). E.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254030/what-are-applications-of-rings-groups?rq=1), [Group theory applications](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65841/group-theory-applications-along-with-a-solved-example?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burnsides lemma is useful for counting objects with many symmetries but whose symmetry groups for each object are not identical.